# Enforce product quantity based on attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, addtocart

I want to make sure a customer cannot set a Quantity other than "1" for some special products. These products all have a special attribute set.

I tried to observe `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after` and manually set the quantity:

```
public function enforceQty (Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $_item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

    // ...

    if ($_item->getQty() > 1) 
    {  
        $_item->setQty(1);
    }
}
```

which works perfectly fine, except that when I try to get the value of said attribute, to identify my special products, I do not get the correct value:

```
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
$_productId = $_product->getId();                                                                                                                                                                                         
$_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$val = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
        ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'special_attr', $storeId);
```

`special_attr` is a boolean attribute. In the HTML output of the product, it shows the correct value `Yes`. In the code above, `$val` gets set to `false` for some reason.

I tried several different ways to get the value of `special_attr`, all of them return `false` instead of `true`.

Any Idea?

**Edit 1:**

I just found a method returning the correct value. Sadly the value returned is language dependent.

```
$val = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load($_product->getId())
        ->getAttributeText('special_attr');
```

Can somebody explain why this method returns the correct value, and the other does not?

**Edit 2:**

After crawling through the sources for getAttributeText, I found that I can get the value I'm looking for like this:

```
$val = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load($_product->getId())
        ->getData('special_attr') == "1"
```

In addition to Question 1: Is there a way to get the actual boolean value, instead of a string value?

Comment: not really an answer to your question, but maybe a solution to the problem. Magento already has a field 'Max Qty allowed in cart'. Why Not use that one. Set the value to 1 for the products you need and problem solved.

Comment: That wold work, but I'd need to make sure these two attributes do not get out of sync. 'special_attribute' does already exist and is used to identify these products.

Answer (score 1):

So I am with Marius here. Magento has this functionality out of the box. Simply update these products so that they have the `Max Qty allowed in cart` as 1. Then this should work straight away.